# Email verification in lumen isn't functioning

Tags: php, authentication, lumen, email-verification

I am new to lumen. I was trying to write a code for email verification, login and registration. Login and registration are working fine. But email verification is not working as expected.

When I run /email/request-verification on postman. It is showing "Unauthorized." as far as I understand the auth middleware in authenticate.php isn't working fine. It is giving false in all cases. Can you please suggest where am I wrong?

Database/migrations/create_users_table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Apps/notifications/verifyemail.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
//Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class VerifyEmail extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
/**
     * The callback that should be used to build the mail message.
     *
     * @var \Closure|null
     */
    public static $toMailCallback;
/**
     * Get the notification's channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array|string
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }
/**
     * Build the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $verificationUrl = $this->verificationUrl($notifiable);
if (static::$toMailCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $verificationUrl);
        }
return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'))
            ->line(Lang::get('Please click the button below to verify your email address.'))
            ->action(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'), $verificationUrl)
            ->line(Lang::get('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.'));
    }
/**
     * Get the verification URL for the given notifiable.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return string
     */
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($notifiable);
return route('email.verify', ['token' => $token], false);
    }
/**
     * Set a callback that should be used when building the notification mail message.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public static function toMailUsing($callback)
    {
        static::$toMailCallback = $callback;
    }
}
```

App/traits/MustverifyEmail.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Traits;
use App\Notifications\VerifyEmail;
trait MustVerifyEmail
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user has verified their email address.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasVerifiedEmail()
    {
        return ! is_null($this->email_verified_at);
    }
/**
     * Mark the given user's email as verified.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function markEmailAsVerified()
    {
        return $this->forceFill([
            'email_verified_at' => $this->freshTimestamp(),
        ])->save();
    }
/**
     * Send the email verification notification.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    {
        $this->notify(new VerifyEmail);
    }
/**
     * Get the email address that should be used for verification.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailForVerification()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

apps/middleware/ensureemailsverified.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
class EnsureEmailIsVerified
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ( $request->fullUrl() != route('email.request.verification') && 
           ( ! $request->user() || ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail() ) )
        {
            throw new AuthorizationException('Unauthorized, your email address '.$request->user()->email.' is not verified.');
        }
return $next($request);
    }
}
```

bootstrap/app/php

```
<?php

require_once _DIR_.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

(new Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables(
    dirname(_DIR_)
))->bootstrap();

date_default_timezone_set(env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
| that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
| application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
|
*/

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    dirname(_DIR_)
);

 $app->withFacades();

 $app->withEloquent();
 $app->configure('jwt');
 $app->register(Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LumenServiceProvider::class);
 $app->configure('mail');

 $app->alias('mail.manager', Illuminate\Mail\MailManager::class);
 $app->alias('mail.manager', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Factory::class);
 
 $app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::class);
 $app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer::class);
 $app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\MailQueue::class);
 
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Container Bindings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
| register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
| your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Config Files
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now we will register the "app" configuration file. If the file exists in
| your configuration directory it will be loaded; otherwise, we'll load
| the default version. You may register other files below as needed.
|
*/

$app->configure('app');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/

// $app->middleware([
//     App\Http\Middleware\ExampleMiddleware::class
// ]);

 $app->routeMiddleware([
     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
 ]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
| are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
| totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
|
*/

// $app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
 $app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
// $app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
| the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
| can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
|
*/
$app->register(Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class);
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'verified' => App\Http\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
]);
$app->withFacades(true, [
    'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification' => 'Notification',
    ]);
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require _DIR_.'/../routes/web.php';
});

return $app;
```

app/model/user.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
//use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
//use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use App\Traits\MustVerifyEmail;


class User extends Model implements Authenticatable, AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, JWTSubject
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, HasFactory, Notifiable, MustVerifyEmail;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token'
    ];


    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

    protected static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();
    
    static::saved(function ($model) {
/**
       * If user email have changed email verification is required
       */
      if( $model->isDirty('email') ) {
        $model->setAttribute('email_verified_at', null);
        $model->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
      }
});
}


}
```

app/http/controllers/authcontrollers.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use App\Notifications\VerifyEmail;

use App\Models\User;
class AuthController extends Controller
{

    /**
  * Request an email verification email to be sent.
  *
  * @param  Request  $request
  * @return Response
  */
  public function emailRequestVerification(Request $request)
  {
    if ( $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail() ) {
        return response()->json('Email address is already verified.');
    }
    
    $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
    
    return response()->json('Email request verification sent to '. Auth::user()->email);
  }
/**
  * Verify an email using email and token from email.
  *
  * @param  Request  $request
  * @return Response
  */
  public function emailVerify(Request $request)
  {
    $this->validate($request, [
      'token' => 'required|string',
    ]);
\Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::getToken();
    \Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
if ( ! $request->user() ) {
        return response()->json('Invalid token', 401);
    }
    
    if ( $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail() ) {
        return response()->json('Email address '.$request->user()->getEmailForVerification().' is already verified.');
    }
$request->user()->markEmailAsVerified();
return response()->json('Email address '. $request->user()->email.' successfully verified.');
  }



    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // $request->user()->fill([
        //     'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword)
        // ])->save();

        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60 * 24
        ]);
    }
}
```

routes/web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    echo "<center> Welcome </center>";
});

$router->get('/version', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});

//Auth::routes(['verified' => true]);

Route::group([

    // 'middleware' => 'auth',
    'prefix' => 'api'

], function ($router) {

    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
    Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

});

$router->group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'verified']], function () use ($router) {
   // $router->post('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
   // $router->get('/user', 'AuthController@user');
    $router->post('/email/request-verification', ['as' => 'email.request.verification', 'uses' => 'AuthController@emailRequestVerification']);
   // $router->post('/refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
    $router->post('/deactivate', 'AuthController@deactivate');
  });
 // $router->post('/register', 'AuthController@register');
 // $router->post('/login', 'AuthController@login');
  $router->post('/reactivate', 'AuthController@reactivate');
  $router->post('/password/reset-request', 'RequestPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
  $router->post('/password/reset', [ 'as' => 'password.reset', 'uses' => 'ResetPasswordController@reset' ]);
  $router->post('/email/verify', ['as' => 'email.verify', 'uses' => 'AuthController@emailVerify']);

$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
  $router->get('users',  ['uses' => 'UsersController@showAllUsers']);

  $router->get('users/{id}', ['uses' => 'UsersController@showOneUser']);

  $router->post('users', ['uses' => 'UsersController@create']);

  $router->delete('users/{id}', ['uses' => 'UsersController@delete']);

  $router->put('users/{id}', ['uses' => 'UsersController@update']);
});
```

app/http/middleware/authenticate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * The authentication guard factory instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

config/auth.php

```
<?php
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */
    /*'defaults' => [
        'guard' => env('AUTH_GUARD', 'api'),
    ],
    */
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "token"
    |
    */
    /*'guards' => [
        'api' => ['driver' => 'api'
    ],
    ],
    */
    'guards' => [
        //'web' => [
        //    'driver' => 'session',
        //    'provider' => 'users',
        //],//from the jwt laravel 9 tutorial
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */
    /*
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Author::class,
        ],
    ],
    */
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => \App\Models\User::class
        ]
        ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
    | that is your password reset e-mail. You may also set the name of the
    | table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
      ],
    'password_timeout' => 10800,
];
```

config/mail.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Mailer
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default mailer that is used to send any email
    | messages sent by your application. Alternative mailers may be setup
    | and used as needed; however, this mailer will be used by default.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mailer Configurations
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure all of the mailers used by your application plus
    | their respective settings. Several examples have been configured for
    | you and you are free to add your own as your application requires.
    |
    | Laravel supports a variety of mail "transport" drivers to be used while
    | sending an e-mail. You will specify which one you are using for your
    | mailers below. You are free to add additional mailers as required.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
    |            "postmark", "log", "array", "failover"
    |
    */

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
            'stream' => [
                'ssl' => [
                   'allow_self_signed' => true,
                   'verify_peer' => false,
                   'verify_peer_name' => false,
                ],
             ],
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs -i'),
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],

        'failover' => [
            'transport' => 'failover',
            'mailers' => [
                'smtp',
                'log',
            ],
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Check the posting my answer, I hope you will get a solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem inside your routes file.

You already put the verification route inside auth middleware and when you trying to call this route auth middleware works and give you 401 unauthorised status.

So you need to move this route `$router->post('/email/request-verification', ['as' => 'email.request.verification', 'uses' => 'AuthController@emailRequestVerification']);` from auth middleware groups outside.

Or you can replace your route with

```
$router->post('/email/request-verification', ['as' => 'email.request.verification', 'uses' => 'AuthController@emailRequestVerification'])->withoutMiddleware(['auth']);
```